# Uncaught TypeError: data is undefined in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables

My problem is I'm making an ajax sever-side call to retrieve an show information, I get a JSON that is an Object with an ArrayList of Objects inside, but when I try to make the call I get the table with a label saying Processing... all the time and this error in the browser log.

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Here it's my HTML:

```
<table id="table_newsletterlist" class="display table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Newsletters attributes -->
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Asunto</th>
                    <th>Para</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Newsletters attributes -->
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Asunto</td>
                    <td>Para</td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Here my JS:

```
$('#table_newsletterlist').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": newsletterUrl,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "newsletters",
            render: function (data){
                return (data.id) ? data.id : "-";
            }
        },
        {"data": "newsletters",
            render: function (data){
                return (data.target) ? data.target : "-";
            }},
        {"data": "newsletters",
            render: function (data){
                return (data.subject) ? data.subject : "-";
            }},
    ]
});
```

And here the JSON I get:

```
{"total":188,"newsletters":[{"id":1,"subject":"Prueba","target":"groups","html":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<title></title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>Probando</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","sender_id":1,"campaign_folder_id":null,"segment_id":null,"group_ids":[],"preview_text":null,"editor_type":"html","url_token":false,"analytics_utm_campaign":"","use_premailer":false}, {more objects like the first...}],"perPage":10,"page":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes:

1. Because your JSON's row data array has the name `newsletters`, you need to refer to this name in the ajax section of your datatable: `"dataSrc": "newsletters"`. This tells DataTables where to look in your JSON for the starting-point of its row iterator.
2. Following on from point 1, now you can refer to the specific fields in each array object, inside your `columns` section - for example: `data: 'id'`.
3. To simplify the use of `-` when there is no data, I recommend using `defaultContent: "-"`. You can use a render function - but that is more complicated than you need here, for your specific example.

The end result is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#table_newsletterlist')
    .DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "http://localhost:7000/newsletters",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": "newsletters"
      },
      "columns": [{
        data: 'id',
        defaultContent: "-"
      }, {
        data: 'subject',
        defaultContent: "-"
      }, {
        data: 'target',
        defaultContent: "-"
      }, {
        data: 'preview_text',
        defaultContent: "-"
      }]
    });

});
```